# parse string in datetime if not valid than set null datetime type of sql in C#

Tags: c#, sql, string, datetime

parse string in datetime if not valid than set null datetime type of sql in C#

```
record.UpdatedOn = DateTime.ParseExact(customerRow.UpdatedOn, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

**error**:String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: What does your string look like? Did you print it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateTime outUpdatedOn = default(DateTime);
if (DateTime.TryParse(customerRow.UpdatedOn, out outUpdatedOn)) record.UpdatedOn = outUpdatedOn; else record.UpdatedOn = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
record.UpdatedOn = 
  DateTime.ParseExact(customerRow.UpdatedOn, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Your are using `null` which means you use the current culture. If that uses a different date-separator than `/` you have a problem. That's why i use `InvariantCulture`.

Read: [The "/" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dateSeparator)

> The "/" custom format specifier represents the date separator, which
>   is used to differentiate years, months, and days. **The appropriate
>   localized date separator is retrieved from the
>   DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator property of the current or specified
>   culture**.

According to the other part of your question how to set a `Nullable<DateTime>` property to `null` if the date is invalid, you should use `DateTime.TryParseExact`:

```
record.UpdatedOn = null;
DateTime updatedOn;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(customerRow.UpdatedOn, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    record.UpdatedOn = updatedOn;
```

Comment: sometime in customerRow.UpdatedOn="NotGiven" same error after using your code.

Comment: @Sandeep: i have already  edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Tim i have added my answer it works after intialize the default variable of DateTime

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the DateTime property to null if it doesn't parse successfully?

```
if(DateTime.TryParse(customerRow.UpdatedOn, out record.UpdatedOn) == false)
    record.UpdatedOn = null;
```

Comment: Thanks @FredrikRedin i have added my answer it works after intialize the default variable of DateTime